# Can I make css "content:" clickable without JS?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

The link "CATEGORIAS" (marked in purple) redirects to the main page and the "+" sign opens a dropdown. So if the user click through the link "CATEGORIAS" would be redirected to the main page.

We want to occupy 100% width of the screen with the :after pseudo-element covering the link. So if the user click in "CATEGORIAS", its really clicking the :after element.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRFn8.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUSHW.jpg

```
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(137,142,236,0.5);
}

span:after {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f067";
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #7f7355;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 3px;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you present your HTML code?

Comment: We are editing a PrestaShop Template and we have no access to edit the HTML so we can only use CSS. Here is the link to our web - http://www.telebelleza.es (The menu appears only in mobile)

Comment: Why would you want the pseudo-element to be clickable and not the span itself? You can't make the pseudo-element clickable. You can however suppress click events from happening on the pseudo-element and make them occur on the element below the pseudo-element.

Comment: @IgnaciodeNuevo it's very important, because in my example (https://jsfiddle.net/r7nzbbhz) everything working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Works for me.

```
.menu-mobile-grover,
.menu-mobile-grover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```